# Why should ReLU only be used in hidden layers?

Tags: neural-network

On [this post](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/10/fundamentals-deep-learning-activation-functions-when-to-use-them/) I read that ReLU should only be used in hidden layers. Why is this like that?

I have a neural network with a regression task. It outputs a number between 0 and 10. I thought ReLU would be a good choice here since it does'nt return numbers smaller than 0. What would be the best activation function for the output layer here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you can still use activation functions for your output layer. I have frequently used Sigmoid activation functions to squash my output in the 0-1 range, and that worked wonderful.

One reason you should consider when using ReLUs is, that they can produce dead neurons. That means that under certain circumstances your network can produce regions in which the network won't update, and the output is always 0.
Essentially, if you have ReLU in your output, you will have no gradient at all, see [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2018/readings/L08%20Optimization.pdf) for more details.

If you are careful during intialization, I don't see why it shouldn't work, though.